# Narayana assuming different colours

Tags: vishnu, yuga

When Yuga dharma normally described, its said that Narayana wears White in Krita, Red in Treta, Yellow in Dwapara and Black in Kali Yuga.
Example, in [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03148.htm).

What are the reasons for changing colours and significance of it?

I have seen this in Mahabharata multiple times and in Puaranas but never came across the explanation.